# How can I get Google Home to spell a word that sounds the same as another?

Tags: google-home, google-assistant

For example: thrown and throne. How can I get Google Home to spell "thrown"? She always assumes I'm asking about "throne"

Saying "How do you spell thrown, as in throw a ball?" makes her spell out "as in throw a ball" too.

This will be very useful for my son, who uses Google Home to help with homework.

Comment: Interesting question, generally the system doesn't seem to be very good with homophones yet.

Comment: Instead of teaching your kid to ask a computer, why don't you teach him to ask you? That's kinda the roll of a parent...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this works for every case, but you can ask Google Home to spell multiple words with context. For example, I just asked my Google Home "How do you spell 'thrown out'?" and it responded with the correct spelling.

It's a pain, but at least this is some sort of workaround.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get Google Home to spell a word that sounds similar to another is to use the phonetic spelling of the word. For example, you could say "spell 'thrown' phonetically" and Google Home should spell out the word as it sounds. Another way is to use context and give a clear sentence or context where the word is used, for example "Can you spell the word thrown as in the past participle of throw" or "Can you spell the word thrown as in "I have thrown the ball"
It may not work every time, but it is worth trying.